# WSL Ubuntu : apt-get error "unable to make backup link"

Tags: apt, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have recently installed the Ubuntu Bash WSL in Win10 (version 1703). When running an apt-get upgrade I get the following error during the installation of Perl (sorry for the formatting):

```
Preparing to unpack .../perl-modules-5.22_5.22.1-9ubuntu0.5_all.deb ...
Unpacking perl-modules-5.22 (5.22.1-9ubuntu0.5) over (5.22.1-9) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/perl-modules-5.22_5.22.1-9ubuntu0.5_all.deb (--unpack):
 unable to make backup link of './usr/share/perl/5.22.1/pod/perldiag.pod' before installing new version: No such file or directory
No apport report written because the error message indicates an issue on the local system
```

The full version string of my shell is (uname -a):

```
Linux CSNLEMARTINEZ 4.4.0-43-Microsoft #1-Microsoft Wed Dec 31 14:42:53 PST 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Creating a symlink makes null sense (just in case somebody thought on that). I checked inside the deb file in /var/cache/apt for any mistakes but it looks OK.

I have already tried the "Windows-style" solution: Uninstalling and reinstalling, to no avail.